# Summing cosines

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Suppose I want to compute $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(n x)/n^{2k}.$$ Now, For any fixed $k$ this is, at least in principle, doable (see the excellent answer to [my math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985778/weighted-sum-of-cosines) a while back), but the question is whether the sequence of polynomials one gets has some sort of a closed form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be written as
$$ F_{2k}(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left(\text{polylog}(2k, e^{ix}) + \text{polylog}(2k, e^{-ix})\right)$$
Note that
 $F_{k}''(x) = -F_{k-2}(x)$, with $F_k(0) = \zeta(k)$ and $F_k'(0) = 0$, so
that $F_k(x) = \zeta(k) + \int_0^x  dt\; (x-t) F_{k-2}(t)$
It seems we have
$$F_{2k}(x) = (-1)^{k+1} \dfrac{x^{2k}}{2(2k)!} + (-1)^k \dfrac{\pi |x^{2k-1}|}{2(2k-1)!}
+ \sum_{j=1}^{k} (-1)^{k-j} \zeta(2j) \dfrac{x^{2k-2j}}{(2k-2j)!}$$

Comment: Nice, that's a cool argument!

Answer (score 6):

We have following known formula by using Fourier series expansion.

$$\forall x\in \mathbb R,B_{2k}(\frac{x}{2\pi})=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}2k!}{2^{2k-1}\pi^{2k}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2k}}\cos(nx)$$

where $B_k(x)$ is Bernoulli polynomials which satisfies in

$$ \frac{t e^{Xt}}{e^t-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n(X) \frac{t^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: Great, thanks! A couple of questions: (a) is there a handy reference? and (b) what happened to the absolute value term (which is there in Robert's answer, but seems to be not there here...)

Comment: E. R. Hansen, A table of series and products, Prentice-Hall (1975). see page 244.

Comment: there is same formula is you change cos to sin by Euler polynomials. This formula is orginally from Euler which wanted to compute zeta function for n=2k . You can find in his original proof such formula. if you assume x=0, then you can compute zeta function for n=2k